# IDENTITY_INSERT ON fails with  error "...is not a user table. Cannot perform SET operation"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've accidentally deleted a row in a database and I would like to reinsert the row. The problem is that the primary key is set to auto increment and `IDENTITY INSERT` is set to `OFF` for the table. I would like to temporarily enable identity insert so I can insert the deleted row, then disable identity insert.

In SQL Server Management Studio I attempted the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable ON

INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, value)
VALUES (241, 'hello', 'hello2')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable OFF
```

The first line fails out with this:

> Msg 8105, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   'myTable' is not a user table. Cannot perform SET operation.

Any idea why?

Comment: is the table name really myTable? Also is this on a remote server?

Comment: Are you in the right database? (not `master`) Did you try with `dbo.MyTable` ??

Comment: Is myTable possibly a synonym for another table?

Comment: SQL Server thinks myTable is not a table, but some other object type such as a view.

Comment: You cannot insert into a view, you need to insert into the base table used in the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error description:
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/not-a-user-table-cannot-perform-set-operation/

myTable doesn't appear to really be a table.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = ‘myTable’
```

What is the xtype?